# Multimedia keys stop working when you restart Spotify app

Tags: keyboard, spotify, media-buttons

I'm using `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` on `Dell XPS 13 9350`. The version of the Spotify app I'm using is `1.1.12.449.g4109e645`.
On startup of my PC, if Spotify is the only music app I open, the media keys work with Spotify whether I'm in the Spotify app or not. As soon as I close Spotify or I open another media player, the media keys stop working with Spotify. Even when I close every media player including Spotify and open Spotify alone, the media keys don't work with Spotify. It only works again when I restart my PC.
Please, is there any solution for this?

I've tried using this solution: [Send media play/pause shortcuts to music player rather than video player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068611/send-media-play-pause-shortcuts-to-music-player-rather-than-video-player). But my settings doesn't let me use media key play/pause as custom shortcut

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 18.04 using the snap version of Spotify the media keys work out of the box, except that Chrome is a little greedy and captures these keys (presumably to control YouTube content and the like).

The good news is that this can be disabled by going to `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling`.

After doing so the media key events will pass-through to Spotify again.

The original solution was from [here](https://gist.github.com/jbonney/5743509#gistcomment-3042597).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, when I restarted Spotify media keys didn't work. So I looked at dbus-monitor output, and apparently VLC was stealing the media keys' focus.

I piped a few commands to get the wrong dbus commands, and forward them to Spotify.

```
dbus-monitor  | grep --line-buffered interface=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player | grep --line-buffered -v spotify | awk -W interactive -F'member=' '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 -I {} dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.{}
```

Save in a .sh file, and run `bash file.sh &`